# How to import more projects into existed workspace in Intellji

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellji 2016 for maven and gradle products. The problem I am facing is that I can't import other maven or gradle projects into my existed workspace. When doing the project import, Intellji will prompt a window to allow me to choose either replace the existed workspace or launch a new workspace window. Is there any way to import them into existed workspace?

Comment: Are they separate projects or nested? I ask as intellij allows one project per workspace.

Comment: They are separate projects

Comment: You can have multiple projects in the same window in Intellij, you need to have each as a separate module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple projects in the same window in Intellij, you need to have each as a separate module.

Create a new "empty project", then when prompted choose "Import module":

[image: Import module]

Comment: If this still doesn't make sense I can upload a screenshot of my projects all in the same Window to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Intellij IDEA. Each project will be in its own window as explained in the user guide:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/opening-multiple-projects.html

Comment: I followed the dkanejs's suggestion and it works fine. I am able to import separate maven modules into one workspace.

Comment: Ohh is that what you meant. Thanks for the feedback.